# Is there any way to have an interface classes which is composed of itself

Tags: c#

In C#, can you have an interface for classes that represent objects that have a one-to-many relationship with themselves?

Here is what I mean, although it doesn't compile:

```
   public interface IComposite<TX> where: typeof(TX)==typeof(this)
   {
      TX Parent { get; }

      IEnumerable<TX> Children { get; } 
   }
```

For example, you might have files/folders in an operating system that contain other files/folders.

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote a good [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) about that sort of pattern (that yes, is valid C#, but heed the warnings included)

Comment: Have you heard about the Composite design pattern? [Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185797/Composite-Design-Pattern) an explanation with C# examples. It avoids having to traverse the graph "from the outside" with getters for children. What do you need this for?

Comment: I have written some code for an engineering application where they need the composite pattern, with objects having 1-many children and one parent.  I was wondering if you could create an interface for the more general situation, then use it to help utilities to assist in building the objects.

Comment: "I was wondering if you could create an interface for the more general situation" -- Did you try? Where is the code for that attempt? What did the code do? How was that different from what you wanted it to do? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No there is no way to do this.

The only constraints you can have on generic type parameters are specified here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx